# Form Data on Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I have a simple login component created with angular like so.

```
<div class="form">
<form (submit) = "loginUser($event)">
<input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
<input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
<button type = "submit">login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

On click of this button I want to be able to print the data to the console which is why I added this functionality.

```
<form (submit) = "loginUser($event)">
```

This is what my .ts file looks like for that same component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.css']
})
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginUser(e){
    var username = e.target.elements[0].value;
    var password = e.target.elements[1].value;
    console.log(username,password);
  }

}
```

When I look at the console I don't see the user name and password that was entered. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Then delete your question if it was a simple thing you missed. Otherwise, if you think it's a good question answer yourself and accept in a day, for future users' benefit.

Comment: Don't I lose points for deleting my question?

Comment: I actually want to see other ways of doing it so I wont delete my question

Comment: Why dont you create a model and bind the html using (ngModel)

Comment: 1. No, but if you do it too often you can get question banned. 2. That's fine then - add the place in the function you added to your answer (two lines of code) and move the "hacky" and request for suggestions to the comments, as it's not part of the answer - I see it got a down vote, so flesh it out a bit. I think the question and answer are OK though.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, it should work. If it doesn't there is something else on your side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form class="k-form" (ngSubmit)="loginUser()>

  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username"  placeholder="username">

  <input type="password"[(ngModel)]="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
</form>
```

**Component**

```
username: string;
password: string;


loginUser(){
  console.log(this.username,this.password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon adding `e.preventDefault()` to the function it seems to work as expected

Comment: This seems like a hacky way of doing things. Any other suggestions??